# Failed to load net_connection_reset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my local system the the application is working fine. When I upload the files to server I am getting the following error:

> failed to load net_err_connection_reset

Comment: It's indicating some missing library/dll.

Comment: I checked for that also all the files are there

Comment: put my code in OnException exception filter and get the details of missing dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Find the missing library using below code.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

try
{
    //The code that causes the error goes here.
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Exception exSub in ex.LoaderExceptions)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(exSub.Message);
        FileNotFoundException exFileNotFound = exSub as FileNotFoundException;
        if (exFileNotFound != null)
        {                
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exFileNotFound.FusionLog))
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Fusion Log:");
                sb.AppendLine(exFileNotFound.FusionLog);
            }
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    string errorMessage = sb.ToString();
    //Display or log the error based on your application.
}
```

Comment: were can i find OnExceptiom Exceptionfilter

Comment: In your base controller, you should override this. Or simply put this code in the action where you are getting exception.